# KnockoutJS: fade in after fading out something else

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, animation, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Say I have a set of 3 radio buttons:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Who" value="Myself" 
            checked="@isMyselfChecked" data-bind="checked: who" />
        Mine
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Who" value="MemberId" 
            checked="@isMemberIdChecked" data-bind="checked: who" />
        I know the member's ID
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Who" value="MemberUrl" 
            checked="@isMemberUrlChecked" data-bind="checked: who" />
        I know the member's URL
    </label>
</div>
```

When the user selects the first radio button (Mine/Myself), no additional input is required. However, when selecting the second or third, additional input *is* required:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="MemberId" placeholder="Enter Member ID" 
        data-bind="toggleWho: who()" style="display: none" />
    <input type="text" name="MemberUrl" placeholder="Enter Member URL" 
        data-bind="toggleWho: who()" style="display: none; width: 450px;" />
</div>
```

It is easy enough to just have `data-bind="visible: who() === '[MemberId|MemberUrl]'"` on the dependent text boxes. However, what if I want to add fade in/out transitions?

I tried out the example custom `fadeVisible` `bindingHandler` from the knockout site, and I understand how it works. However this will fade out and fade in the text boxes at the same time. If radio `'MemberId'` is selected, and user selects `'MemberUrl'` radio, I want the `MemberId` text box to fade out *before* the `MemberUrl` text box fades in.

Below is what I have now, and it works, but I don't think it's optimal. How else can knockout be told to not perform the fade in until a previous element has been faded out? Do I need another `ko.observale`, or possibly a `ko.computed`?

```
var viewModel = {
    fadeSpeed: 150,
    who: ko.observable($('input[type=radio][name=Who]:checked').val())
};

ko.bindingHandlers.toggleWho = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        if (unwrapped === element.name)
            $(element).show();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        // when selected value is myself, fade out the visible one, if any
        if (unwrapped === 'Myself') {
            $('input[type=text][name=MemberId]:visible')
                .fadeOut(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
            $('input[type=text][name=MemberUrl]:visible')
                .fadeOut(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
        }

            // when selected value is memberid, may need to fade out url first
        else if (unwrapped === 'MemberId') {
            if ($('input[type=text][name=MemberUrl]:visible').length > 0) {
                $('input[type=text][name=MemberUrl]:visible')
                    .fadeOut(viewModel.fadeSpeed, function () {
                        $('input[type=text][name=MemberId]')
                            .fadeIn(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
                    });
            } else {
                $('input[type=text][name=MemberId]')
                    .fadeIn(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
            }
        }

            // when selected value is memberurl, may need to fade out id first
        else if (unwrapped === 'MemberUrl') {
            if ($('input[type=text][name=MemberId]:visible').length > 0) {
                $('input[type=text][name=MemberId]:visible')
                    .fadeOut(viewModel.fadeSpeed, function () {
                        $('input[type=text][name=MemberUrl]')
                            .fadeIn(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
                });
            } else {
                $('input[type=text][name=MemberUrl]')
                    .fadeIn(viewModel.fadeSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to adapt this a little to fit your example, but I needed to simplify it to test in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXg9Z/5/).

Here is the binding:

```
var previousElement = null;
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeSwitcher = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            if (previousElement == null) { // initial fade
                $(element).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $(previousElement).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $(element).fadeIn();
                });
            }
            previousElement = element;
        }        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but maybe it is of use to someone else.

I've taken Tyrsius' answer and changed it to fix my own needs; this version deals with an observable property and will fadeOut/fadeIn the old/new value whenever it changes.

```
Usage example: <span data-bind="fadeSwitcher: myObservable"></span>

ko.bindingHandlers.fadeSwitcher = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        element.setAttribute('previousValue', value);
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, ko.observable(value));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var previousValue = element.getAttribute('previousValue');
        if (value !== previousValue) {
            $(element).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, ko.observable(value));
                $(element).fadeIn();
            });
            element.setAttribute('previousValue', value);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tyrsius for the answer. I did have to adapt it from the fiddle. I was able to use a slightly modified binding to get it to work with the same radios as in the question (without a foreach):

```
@* radios same as in question *@
<div>
    <input type="text" name="MemberId" placeholder="Enter Member ID" 
        data-bind="whoFader: who() === 'MemberId'" style="display: none" />
    <input type="text" name="MemberUrl" placeholder="Enter Member URL" 
        data-bind="whoFader: who() === 'MemberUrl'" 
        style="display: none; width: 450px;" />
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.whoFader = {
    previousElement: null,
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            if (this.previousElement == null) {
                $(element).fadeIn('fast');
            } else {
                $(this.previousElement).hide();
                $(element).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            this.previousElement = element;
        }
        else {
            $(element).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to consider a more model oriented solution. Things will tend to work out simpler with KO if you follow the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Tyrsius, by "model oriented solution", do you mean using a foreach to render the radios from the vm instead of outputing them explicitly in HTML?

Comment: Yes, among other things. The idea in the MVVM pattern is that the view doesn't hold any data, it only knows about how to display your model. All the data should be in the model. This allows both the view and the model to be used by any data.